# Index a Table with Geometry Column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table called `Stores` with 10k rows which has a column `location geometry(Point,4326)`.

```
CREATE INDEX "Stores_spatial_gix"
ON "Stores"
USING gist
(location);
```

Upon KNN query

```
explain analyze select *
 from "Stores"
 order by ST_distance_sphere(location,st_point(-82.373978, 29.633657)) limit 3
```

I get about 800ms each time. What am I doing wrong that it takes so long time?

Comment: You have a full table scan query there, requiring that distance be calculated for each row, then the results be sorted.  I'm amazed the query is that fast -- the table contents must be cached.

Comment: Well this is just some preliminary data. There will be 1M+ rows.

Comment: Then that query will take forever if you don't add an ST_DWithin constraint.

Comment: I have benchmarked and a table with `point` column and an index gives out the same KNN query in 0.452 ms! So there is something definitely off here. Due to some library dependency I'm stuck with `geometry` and can't use `point`. So it is possible, but needs a right approach.

Comment: x-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31369847/398670 (for anyone else looking later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PostGIS 2+, you can make use of the `<->` operator.  See http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html

So in your example it might look like

```
SELECT * FROM Stores
ORDER BY location <-> 'SRID= 4326;POINT(-82.373978 29.633657)'::geometry limit 3;
```

Note the results may be returned misordered.

If you can put an ST_DWithin constraint in too, that may help out.

Comment: Does the same inaccuracy apply when I do `point <-> point` for KNN?

Comment: Inaccuracy in the ordering?

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia, any progress?

Comment: Yes, this approach works. As you mentioned it might suffer from misorderings. I ended up using a hybrid approach as I explain in a new answer here. Also there should be no comma in constructing point, but I couldn't edit the answer

Comment: Updated. Feel free to mark as complete

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
WITH index_query AS (
  SELECT ST_distance_sphere(location, 'SRID=4326;POINT(-82.373978 29.633657)'::geometry) as distance, ST_X("Stores"."location"), ST_Y("Stores"."location")
    FROM "Stores"
  ORDER BY location <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(-82.373978 29.633657)'::geometry LIMIT 100) 
  SELECT * 
   FROM index_query 
  ORDER BY distance limit 10;
```

Results are spit out in `2.5ms` in a table with 1M geometry records. The hybrid idea is taken from [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html) to avoid misorderings.